# Appending query based on condition in sql stored procedure

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2005

In my .net 2.0 application I want to convert all the inline queries to sql stored procedures.

I have queries like

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();    
**query.AppendLine("Select * from xxx Where 1 =1");**

if(Id != 0)    
query.AppendLine("And Id = @Id");

if(Nemae != null)    
query.AppendLine("And Name = @Name");
```

How could I write this in sql stored procedure?

Do I need to repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably like this :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA
WHERE (@PARAM1 = 0 OR ID=@PARAM1) AND (@Name = NULL OR COLUMN2=Name)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: `@Name = NULL...` – this only works when ANSI_NULLS is set to OFF and the default is ON. Instead this will work as intended regardless of ANSI_NULLS setting: `@Name IS NULL OR...`. (Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass parameters to stored procedures and use them like this:

```
CREATE PROC spTest
(
    @name varchar(30)=NULL
    , @id int=NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE (@name IS NULL OR name = @name)
    AND    (@id IS NULL OR id = @id)
END
```

Comment: No I donot want to perform any check when Name is Null i.e if name is null there will not be a where condition for it